# Method Not Found JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want show up a list with names that I put in a InputText. 
But when I call the method I get the error: Method not found
Can anyone help me?

MyBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="guestBean")public class Exer02_30 {

    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String message;
    public String nameSearch;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getNameSearch() {
        return nameSearch;
    }

    public void setNameSearch(String nameSearch) {
        this.nameSearch = nameSearch;
    }

    public ResultSet getContacts() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/GuestBook", "root", "Ds881536");
        try{
          PreparedStatement getContacts = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT NAME, EMAIL, MESSAGE FROM CONTACTS");
          CachedRowSet rowSet = new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();       
          rowSet.populate(getContacts.executeQuery());       
          return rowSet;
        }
        finally{

            conn.close();
        }
    }

    public String save() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, Exception{

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/GuestBook", "root", "Ds881536");
        try{

            PreparedStatement addEntry = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO CONTACTS (NAME, EMAIL, MESSAGE) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
            addEntry.setString(1, getName());
            addEntry.setString(2, getEmail());
            addEntry.setString(3, getMessage());

            addEntry.executeUpdate();
            return "exer02_30.xhtml";
        }
        finally{

            conn.close();
        }
    }

    public ResultSet getSearch()throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/GuestBook", "root", "Ds881536");
        try{
          PreparedStatement getSearch = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT NAME, EMAIL, MESSAGE FROM CONTACTS WHERE NAME = ?");
          getSearch.setString(1, getNameSearch());
          CachedRowSet rowSet = new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();       
          rowSet.populate(getSearch.executeQuery());       
          return rowSet;
        }
        finally{

            conn.close();
        }
    }

}
```

JSF FILE

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Guest Book: Add Entry</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Guest Book: Add Entry</h1>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputText value="Name:"/>
                <h:inputText id="nameInputText" value="#{guestBean.name}"/>
                <br/>
                <h:outputText value="Email:"/>
                <h:inputText id="emailInputText" value="#{guestBean.email}"/>
                <br/>
                <h:outputText value="Message:"/>
                <h:inputText id="messageInputText" value="#{guestBean.message}"/>
                <br/>               
            </h:panelGrid>
            <br/>
            <h:commandButton id="ajax" value="Save Contact" action="#{guestBean.save()}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
            </h:commandButton>           
            <h:dataTable value="#{guestBean.contacts}" var="contacts"
                     rowClasses="oddRows.evenRows" headerClass="header"
                     styleClass="table" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"
                     >
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                #{contacts.NAME}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Email</f:facet>
                #{contacts.EMAIL}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Message</f:facet>
                #{contacts.MESSAGE}
            </h:column>
           </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
        <h:form id="form">
            <h:panelGroup id="wrapper">
                <h:dataTable value="#{guestBean.search}" var="contacts"
                     rowClasses="oddRows.evenRows" headerClass="header"
                     styleClass="table" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"
                     >
                <h:column>
                   <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                   #{contacts.NAME}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                   <f:facet name="header">Email</f:facet>
                   #{contacts.EMAIL}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Message</f:facet>
                    #{contacts.MESSAGE}
                </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
                <h:commandButton id="ajax2" value="Save Contact" action="#{guestBean.search}">
                  <f:ajax render=":form:wrapper"/>
                </h:commandButton> 
                <h:outputText value="Search:"/>
                <h:inputText id="searchInputText" value="#{guestBean.nameSearch}"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: which method is not found?

Comment: @paulo 1) Use one type of xmlns namespaces Refer [JSF Tag Libraries](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/toc.htm) 2) [choose the right bean scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)  .

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this (without parentheses)?

```
<h:commandButton id="ajax" value="Save Contact" action="#{guestBean.save}">
     <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: if a method takes no arguments it does not matter

Comment: i agreed with @thatsIch -1

Comment: ouch sorry then, i guess i mixed it up with actionListener